# Android: Compose navigation arguments are not being passed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

I have a very simple application ui made with Compose.

3 screens for now: login, items list and item details.

The problem is when i click on an item in the items list, i navigate to the item details and i pass the item ID as nav arg.

The problem is, I can't retrieve it and the arguments bundle is empty.

Here is my code:

`MainActivity`:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            AdrestoApplication()
        }
    }
}
```

Main Composable:

```
@Composable
fun AdrestoApplication() {
    val authViewModel = hiltViewModel<AuthViewModel>()

    val navController = rememberNavController()
    val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
    val isLoggedIn = authViewModel.isLoggedIn()
    val initialRoute =
        if (isLoggedIn) Destinations.LISTINGS_LIST else Destinations.LOGIN_ROUTE
    val currentRoute = navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route ?: initialRoute

    AdrestoTheme {
        NavGraph(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = currentRoute,
        )
    }
}
```

`NavGraph`:

```
object Destinations {
    const val LOGIN_ROUTE = "login"
    const val HOME_ROUTE = "home"
    const val ORDER_DETAILS = "order_details"
    const val ORDERS_LIST = "orders_list"
    const val LISTING_DETAILS = "listing_details/{listingId}"
    const val LISTINGS_LIST = "listings_list"
}

@Composable
fun NavGraph(
    navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController(),
    startDestination: String = Destinations.LOGIN_ROUTE,
) {
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = startDestination) {
        composable(Destinations.LOGIN_ROUTE) {
            Login(
                navController = navController,
            )
        }
        composable(Destinations.LISTINGS_LIST) {
            ListingsScreen(
                navController = navController,
            )
        }
        composable(
            Destinations.LISTING_DETAILS,
            arguments = listOf(navArgument("listingId") { type = NavType.LongType })
        ) {
            Log.d("Navhost","NavGraph: the nav arg found is: ${it.arguments!!.getLong("listingId")}") // logs 0
            ListingScreen(
                navController = navController,
                listingId = it.arguments!!.getLong("listingId"),
            )
        }
    }
}
```

The part of the UI that triggers the navigation with argument:

```
LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(all = 8.dp)
        .background(MaterialTheme.colors.background)
) {
    items(listings.value.data ?: listOf()) { listing ->
        Listing(
            listing = listing,
            onCardClick = {
                Log.d("some tag", "ListingsScreen: navigating to ${listing.id}") // logs as expected
                val route = "listing_details/${listing.id}"
                Log.d("some tag", "ListingsScreen: the route is $route") //logs listing_details/418 (for example)
                navController.navigate(route)
            },
        )
    }
}
```

I can't understand what's going wrong here, isn't the composables in the same navgraph?

I have another issue which is when i press the back button, the navigation don't go up but it closes the app (like if there is not backstack...).

Comment: I've copied the significant parts of your code and it works fine to me. Here's [my sample](https://gist.github.com/PhilipDukhov/4d698ddade0f1dedab5b565060089a5b). Check out if my sample still doesn't work for you. If so, which compose/navigation version are you using?

Comment: I tested your example and it worked fine, but i don't see any difference between our codes...

Comment: I should mention that if i don't pass the navController to the compose screens (login, items list...), and try accessing it by rememberNavController() i get nullpointer exception.

Comment: `rememberNavController` shouldn't return some current nav controller, it should create a new one. `NullPointerException` is probably about the new `NavConrtoller` is missing needed routes. The recommended way is passing a block instead, like `onCardClick: (Int) -> Unit` and doing all the navigation stuff inside `NavGraph` in the callbacks. Yet it you can pass it as you're doing it right now, it should work fine. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) where we'll be able to reproduce the problem..

Comment: yes i just tried passing a block instead, but it still the same...

Comment: I'll try sharing more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the start destination argument of the `NavGraph`, I was reinitializing (unkowingly) the navController backstack each time I navigated to a new screen.

```
@Composable
fun AdrestoApplication() {
    val authViewModel = hiltViewModel<AuthViewModel>()

    val navController = rememberNavController()
    val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
    val isLoggedIn = authViewModel.isLoggedIn()
    val initialRoute =
        if (isLoggedIn) Destinations.LISTINGS_LIST else Destinations.LOGIN_ROUTE
    val currentRoute = navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route ?: initialRoute

    AdrestoTheme {
        NavGraph(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = currentRoute, // this was issue, changed to a static initial route.
        )
    }
}
```